# Mapping with D3.js: Adding properties to json map vs binding external (csv) data

Tags: json, csv, d3.js

First off, my apologies if this is the wrong forum for this question, or if it's been asked and answered in another post elsewhere.

I'm getting started creating interactive maps using D3.js, and Scott Murray's book has proven to be a tremendous resource. However, one thing I am still a bit confused about on a design/philosophical level is this: The majority of the tutorials I've found online focus on mapping using both a data file (.csv) and a file for the geometries (.geojson, .topojson, etc.).

Is there a particular advantage to binding data that is stored in an external file, such as a .csv file, to geographic areas versus simply adding that data as a property to the .json object(s)? In essence, why work with two files when you could simply work with one, especially if the map is not going to be updated?

Any insights on why this seems to be the preferred would be much appreciated.

Comment: The only advantage is that you can use multiple data sources that are loaded on demand or changing data sources with the same geodata. If that doesn't apply in your case, you may as well go with a single data source.

Comment: Thanks, Lars. Glad to know there's no fundamental issue at hand that I'm overlooking at least in this instance. Cheers!